# Mongoose: query database excluding results which contains non latin characters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a database containing data in different languages, and I would like to exclude from my query results which contains text written with non latin characters (arabic, hebrew, greek...). Is it possible using the standard mongoose functions?

I would like something like this:

```
QuoteModel.find({$where:"this.text != <non latin characters>"}, function(error, quotes) {...}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply regex on MongoDB query to fetch only documents containing latin text.

```
db.collection.find({news:{$regex:"[\p{L}\s]+"}})
```

I have following input documents in collection

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f5326f70f5f66368e340b2"), 
        "news" : ". قد ضرب النزاع التجارية تشيكوسلوفاكيا"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f532e85a4b38f73c1ef8ce"), 
        "news" : "אודות לחיבור עוד, אודות מונחונים ארכיאולוגיה את"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f5331b5a4b38f73c1ef8cf"), 
        "news" : "Tota adversarium vis eu. Meis choro epicuri vel at"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f533725a4b38f73c1ef8d0"), 
        "news" : "exploding star's shockwave has been captured in visible light by NASA"
    }
]
```

After running above query, I get

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f5331b5a4b38f73c1ef8cf"), 
        "news" : "Tota adversarium vis eu. Meis choro epicuri vel at"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f533725a4b38f73c1ef8d0"), 
        "news" : "exploding star's shockwave has been captured in visible light by NASA"
    }
]
```